# Passing multiple certificates through Curl request using Guzzle

Tags: php, api, certificate, guzzle

I have an http request that uses a key, certificate, and certificate chain. How can it be translated to Guzzle? The problem is that I do not know how to add all my certificates to the Guzzle request. In the documentation there is an example for only one certificate

Example of my request:

```
// curl -vvv -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json' --cacert client-bundle.pem --key key.pem --cert cert.pem 'my_url'
```

My function is sending a request using Guzzle at the moment:

```
try {
$response = $this->request('POST', 'my_url', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept' => 'application/json'
                ],

            ]);

return Json::decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
            $this->checkResponse($result);

        } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
}
```

I tried to find an example of sending a request with the transfer of several certificates. I could not find such an example, using only one certificate does not suit me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add multiple certificates to a Guzzle request, you can use the ssl_key and cert options in the request options array. The ssl_key option can be set to the path of your private key file, and the cert option can be set to the path of your certificate file.

```php
$certFile = 'cert.pem';
$keyFile = 'key.pem';
$caFile = 'client-bundle.pem';

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

try {
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'my_url', [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'cert' => [$certFile, $keyFile],
        'ssl_key' => $keyFile,
        'verify' => $caFile
    ]);

    $result = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    $this->checkResponse($result);

    return Json::decode($result);

} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: in this snippet `'cert' => [$certFile, $keyFile],` `$keyFile` is ssl key file or passphrase?

Comment: @MaxP. s ssl key. To pass the passphrase, I used the following construction: `'ssl_key' => [$keyFile], $passPhrase]`

Answer (score -1):

Using the cat command, I combined the certificates into one file

```
cat *.pem >> cert-pem-bundle.pem
```

After that, the resulting file was used in the cert parameter. Final function:

```
try {

            $response = $this->request('POST', 'my_url', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept' => 'application/json'
                ],
                'cert' => ['/app/cert-pem-bundle.pem', 'testtest'], // testtest - pass phrase
            ]);

            $result = Json::decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
            return $result;
        } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: Looks like a bad practice combining keys in a single file.

Comment: I agree. But this was the first solution I found. Later I used the solution proposed by Mehdi